# Is there a way to get a boolean value based on whether a component has been rendered to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to set a class to my entire app if a certain component is rendered. This component is a loading spinner that appears in multiple places. I want to apply styling to everything else in the app if the `Loading` component isn't rendered.

Is there a way to determine which components have been rendered, and conditionally apply styling (for example) based on whether that value is true or false?

My only other idea is to set a redux value and manually switching it on and off where I'm conditionally rendering the `Loading` component, then styling conditionally based on that.

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
const isLoading = DOM.Loading.isRendered

return (
 <App className={`app ${isLoading && "dark-mode"}`}/>
)
```

Comment: How are you going to apply styling if the component is not rendered?

Comment: I want to apply styling to **everything else** if the component isn't rendered. I'll edit my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: I would use the context API to hold the loading state. Each child component that needs to know about this and update its styles can be a child of your context Provider. This way, you can avoid prop drilling while still being able to adjust the styles of components deep within your react tree

Comment: I'll do that with Redux. I thought that might be the only option but thought I'd ask anyway. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: document.getElementById()?

Answer (score 0):

If it's for styling purposes and you will handle it just by adding or removing classes to the container (in this case, to the #App container), just use the same principle for detecting the components:

Add a unique id/class to any HTML element in the component's HTML, and then check if it exists in the DOM.